# PST Capture 2.0 won't install

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-migration, outlook

I am preparing our organisation to migrate from an ISP hosted e-mail account to MS Exchange Online hosting. We need to migrate existing mail into the new accounts before doing the final switch over. Microsoft provides a tool called [PST Capture](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=36789) that will automate the uploading of existing mail from PST files to their hosted accounts - but it won't install on my server, which is running 2008 R2, and Powershell 4.0.

The installer gets right up to the part where it should copy files, then gives the following error:

```
You must have Windows PowerShell 3.0 installed in order to install this product.
```

Initially PowerShell 2.0 was installed. I tried all in my power to upgrade to version 3.0 specifically. Every time I ran the Powershell installer, it gave an error to the effect that this update was not applicable. Eventually I ran Windows Update over and over until no outstanding updates were left, then the Powershell installer ran, but updated to version 4.0.

Does anyone know of a workaround to get PST capture to install with Powershell 4.0, or a way I can downgrade to PowerShell 3.0?

[image: Screen Shot of Powershell Version]

Comment: Well that's very annoying. Especially since the download page says 'PowerShell 3.0 *or later*'.  Have you rebooted since installing all the updates?

Comment: We've had a weekend-long power outage, so the machine booted this morning. Plus I rebooted the server several times during the update process. I tried again just before posting my question - same error. It is very annoying!

Comment: seems silly, but I wonder if you were to go into PS, then run `Powershell -Version "3.0"` and then browse in that PS console to the PST Capture installer and run the setup if it will take.  I'm wondering if it horribly looks during setup for just 3.0 though...if that's the case, depending on where it is looking it still may fail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @TheCleaner - I tried following your suggestion - but the problem persists. Exact same error message.

Comment: OK - so the official position of Microsoft is that the tool is unsupported. That leaves trying to downgrade / uninstall PowerShell 4.0 and see if I can install 3.0. I don't have high hopes.